# VS 2005 Multiple Startup Project

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I've have a project which has 11 mini-project...
I choose 2 of my project to start when project is browsing...
My first project is web other one is desttop project...
While i choose start without debugging is work fine: 2 of my projects start well...
But when i choose to debug mode my desktop project is not starting, thus i can't debug my project...Just my web project  is starting and thats's all, it is not working as same as in the without debuging mode...

Summary: 2 project is not working properly as same as in the debug mode and in the without debug mode...

Answer (score 0):

Anytime during debugging your can right click a project in the solution explorer and start it for debugging. That way you can start as many projects as you wish.

Comment: may be it can be a solution but when ever i start to project will i do the same thing ? that's not the exact point of my problem.But thanks